# Why F-Bounded Type is used to add new method on existing type hierarchy

Tags: java, generics, f-bounded-polymorphism

I was reading following paper about solving Expression Problem using Java Generics.

http://www.daimi.au.dk/~madst/ecoop04/main.pdf

The author propose the first solution using the F-Bounded types to ensure left and right parameters are of type EvalExp.

I tried to solve the problem without using the F-Bounded type and ended up with following code which seems to work

```
public interface Exp {
    void print();
}

public class Lit implements Exp {
    public int value;
    Lit(int value) { this.value = value; }
    public void print() { System.out.print(value); }
}

public class Add<C extends Exp> implements Exp {
    public C left, right;

    public Add(final C left, final C right) {
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }

    @Override
    public void print() {
        left.print(); System.out.print("+"); right.print();
    }
}

public interface EvalExp extends Exp {
     int eval();
}

public class EvalLit extends Lit implements EvalExp {
    public EvalLit(int value) { super(value); }

    @Override
    public int eval() { return value; }
}

public class EvalAdd<A extends EvalExp> extends Add<A> implements EvalExp {

    public EvalAdd(A left, A right) {
        super(left, right);
    }

    @Override
    public int eval() {
        return left.eval() + right.eval();
    }
}
```

Does this solution solve the Expression Problem (will it be extensible for new data and operations)?

Does is satisfy code level extensibility (see the papers for details).

Does above solution has any disadvantages over the F-Bounded solution proposed in the paper?

Any explanation is welcome.

Edit: Updated the code to fix the compilation issue.

Comment: The code doesn't compile. Should it be `public class Add<C extends Exp> implements Exp {` (instead of `C extends Eval`)?